# Refresh not working when using spring cloud starter and fabric8

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-kubernetes

I think that there is an issue when using these two dependencies in the same projet. I'm talking about `spring-cloud-starter` and `spring-cloud-starter-kubernetes-fabric8-config`.

I'm using

- Spring Boot : 2.7.7
- Spring Cloud : 2021.0.5

What i'm trying to build is a spring boot application on kubernetes. Each time a configmap or a sercret get changed, the app context should be updated with the new values. To achieve this, i'm using the spring cloud watcher.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-kubernetes/docs/current/reference/html/#spring-cloud-kubernetes-configuration-watcher

For the configmap part, everything works fine but when i tried to use a secret i noticed a strange behavior. The spring watcher calls my pods on the /actuator/refresh endpoint but nothing get updated. Actually, even on my local machine, the /refresh endpoint returns 200_OK but nothing is updated.
Here's the code snippet :

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-kubernetes-fabric8-config</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "metadata")
@PropertySource(value = "classpath:acl-default.yaml", factory = YamlPropertySourceFactory.class)
@PropertySource(value = "file:${user.home}/acls/acl.yaml", factory = YamlPropertySourceFactory.class, ignoreResourceNotFound = true)
@Slf4j
@Getter
@Setter
public class ACLConfig implements InitializingBean {

    private List<User> users;
```

The ACLConfig class will load our users credentials let's say based on a file from the files system under `${user.home}/acls/acl.yaml` otherwise it will get loaded from the classpath.

The content of `${user.home}/acls/acl.yaml` is :

```
metadata:
  users:
    - name: Richard
      password: kjqsd78jkdq-local
    - name: Richard
      password: jqsd98ds78-local
    - name: Richard
      password: kSkjqf887qsd-local
```

bootstrap.properties

```
server.port=8080
spring.application.name=demo
spring.cloud.kubernetes.config.sources[0].name=${spring.application.name}
spring.cloud.kubernetes.config.sources[0].namespace=spring-cloud-watcher
```

application.properties

```
logging.level.root=INFO
logging.level.com.example.demo=DEBUG
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=info,health,refresh
spring.config.import=optional:file:${user.home}/acls/acl.yaml
```

So as i said, this example does not work (the acl file update will not trigger the spring context refresh).

To make it work, you have to :

- delete the `spring-cloud-starter-kubernetes-fabric8-config` dependency from `pom.xml`,
- change the content of `${user.home}/acls/acl.yaml`,
- call the `/actuator/refresh`,
- check the logs :  you'll see that ACLConfig -> users List will be updated

You can find the example on my repo : https://github.com/mamdouni/spring-watcher-example

Delete the fabric8 dependency is not an option for me because i need to run this on kubernetes but i don't understand why it blocks the context refresh !!!

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: spring-cloud-kubernetes contributor here: first things first is to upgrade to version `3.x.x` of the spring kubernetes dependencies. If it reproduces with the upgraded version is to go to our github project and open an issue, I would be more than glad to take a closer look. Unfortunately, version `2021.0.5` though supported, I don't do any fixes other there, only on the latest version.

Comment: Thanks for the tip @Eugene. 
Works fine using : spring cloud 2022.0.1 and spring boot 3.0.2. 
Put it below and i'll accept it as answer.

Comment: that is OK, you can post an answer yourself, and I will be glad to upvote it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned by @Eugene in the first comment, it was an incompatibility issue between spring boot 2 and spring cloud.
It worked fine after upgrading to spring boot 3.